# Altering a column (null -> not null) without knowing the data type

Tags: sql-server

Is there a possibility to alter a column from "allows null" to "does not allow null" without knowledge of the actual data type of the column?

I think no, so I have made as the basic skeleton code for my stored procedure:

```
SELECT t.name,c.max_length FROM sys.types t 
LEFT JOIN sys.columns c ON(t.system_type_id = c.system_type_id) 
WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID(@TableName) AND c.name=@FieldName;
```

and

```
EXEC('UPDATE ' + @TableName + ' SET ' + @FieldName + ' = ' + @DefaultValue + ' WHERE ' + @FieldName + ' IS NULL');
EXEC('ALTER TABLE ' + @TableName + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + @FieldName + ' NOT NULL');
```

I guess now I only have to get the return values from the first query back into the second. I can't get my head around how to get the values into a variable and then access them again. Ideas?

Comment: Your first query is broken. You have variables stuck in the middle of your string...unless you are using parameterized dynamic sql. The real challenge here is it is not at all clear what you are trying to do. And of course you are missing another logical element of this type of change. You are trying to set a column to not allow null but you don't check to see if there are any rows with NULL for that column. If there are, this will throw an exception. Perhaps an explanation of the requirements are in order.

Comment: With your latest edit you still have some issues. You can't just set a column to not null in an alter statement. It MUST include the datatype.

Comment: I modified my question to include your suggestions. The requirement is that I want to keep the data type of a column, without knowing what that was, but set the column to "not null" before adding the PK.

Comment: @SeanLange that's exactly what I am asking about - how to achieve that without knowing the datatype beforehand.

Comment: You did the hard part, finding the information in the sys tables. Now it is just basic t-sql and @TabAlleman posted a great example already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` has all required information and is part of a SQL standard, it might be better to use that in this case (however, SQL Server's `ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN` is non-standard anyway so it might not matter as much).

Either way, you should also be checking for whether there's character length and/or numeric precision being specified, and make sure you're altering the table in the correct schema (and not getting `dbo.TableName` instead of `customschema.TableName`).  You could try something like this (I used `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` here but you could easily refactor this to use the `sys.columns` view):

```
DECLARE @retVal VARCHAR(500);
SELECT @retVal = 
    CASE WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH > 0
        THEN CONCAT(DATA_TYPE, '(', CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH ,')')
        WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1 AND DATA_TYPE <> 'xml'
        THEN CONCAT(DATA_TYPE, '(MAX)')
        WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('numeric', 'decimal')
        THEN CONCAT(DATA_TYPE, '(', NUMERIC_PRECISION,',', NUMERIC_SCALE,')')
        ELSE DATA_TYPE
        END 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @schemaName
    AND TABLE_NAME = @tableName
    AND COLUMN_NAME = @columnName
```

`@retVal` will now capture datatypes like `int`, `varchar(100)`, `varbinary(MAX)`, or `decimal(10,2)` correctly.

And then build up a dynamic SQL Query like this:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @schemaName + '.' + @tableName + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + @columnName + ' ' + @retVal + ' NOT NULL;'
EXEC(@sql);
```

Comment: A previous version of this post incorrectly assumed that if NUMERIC_PRECISION was NOT NULL then it needed to be specified - double checked that and that's not null for `int`s and `bigint`s etc.

Comment: I have to respectfully disagree that you should use INFORMATION_SCHEMA views instead of the system tables. They are ok for some things but they simply completely miss a number of important pieces of information. Seems that Aaron Bertrand agrees. https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views

Comment: In this case, all the  needed data is present in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA, and that should last better through upgrades than the sys.* views.  But it's not inherently wrong to use the sys views, and this query could certainly be refactored to use them easily.

Comment: Then again, I suppose SQL Server's `ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN` syntax would need to be changed if ported anyway, so maybe it matters less in this case.

Comment: Agreed that in this case it has all the required info. I doubt that sql server will be going away from the sys views anytime soon, or ever. Everything in their code is based on it. When the information need is in the information_schema views they are certainly a lot more friendly to work with. Either way a +1 from me.

Comment: Thanks - I've updated my question to reflec tthis, and thanks for the read.  Also updated to capture case of `(MAX)` for varchar/varbinary.

Comment: I converted to using sys.columns and sys.systypes, and columns.max_length returns actual numbers for fixed-length types.  I added a condition for when systypes.variable = 1, then add the max_length value.

Answer (score 3):

You select values into variables like this:

```
SELECT @Var1=t.name,@Var2=c.max_length FROM sys.types t 
LEFT JOIN sys.columns c ON(t.system_type_id = c.system_type_id) 
WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID(@TableName) AND c.name=@FieldName;
```

This of course assumes that you have already declared Var1 & Var2, and that your query will only return one row.